# SDM extra value from MODIS

Tags: raster, r-maptools, dismo

I am trying to extract monthly sea surface temperature, monthly chlorophyll concentration, depth, salintity via R.
My tibble consist of 10000 presence-only data with columns of year, month, data, latitude and longitude.

How can I extract the value response to each data point and combine them into a table?

I have tried using MODISSsubset, but there is an error.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(hb_df)) {
  longitude <- hb_df$decimalLongitude[i]
  latitude <- hb_df$decimalLatitude[i]
  year <- hb_df$year[i]
  month <- hb_df$month[i]

# Use MODISSubsets function to retrieve the SST data
  sst_data <- MODISSubsets(lon = longitude, lat = latitude, product = "sst", year = year, month = month)}
```